# How to use string formatting to dynamically assign variables

Tags: python, string, variables, attributes, format

In Python, I am populating an object to model the configuration, environment and other aspects related to rsyslog on the local machine (RHEL 6.4 Python 2.6.4)  I loop through many instances of the rsyslog daemon (this_instance_number), and many attributes (attribute) defined in a configuration file.

With those value I populate the object.

Given the following variables:

```
this_instance_number=5
attribute="startupscript"
```

The following line of code,

```
print ('rsyslog.instance%(instance_number)s.%(attribute)s' %\
      {"instance_number": this_instance_number, "attribute": attribute})
```

will print this text:

```
rsyslog.instance5.startupscript
```

How can I then assign the attribute that text would refer to to a value based on that format string?

For example, if hard coded, I would assign:

```
rsyslog.instance5.startupscript="/etc/init.d/sample"
```

But, I want to assign it something like this:

```
('rsyslog.instance%(instance_number)s.%(attribute)s' %\
      {"instance_number": this_instance_number, "attribute": attribute}) = variable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `getattr()` to dynamically retrieve attributes:

```
instance = getattr(rsyslog, 'instance{}'.format(this_instance_number))
print getattr(instance, attribute)
```

and `setattr()` to assign:

```
instance = getattr(rsyslog, 'instance{}'.format(this_instance_number))
setattr(instance, attribute, variable)
```

or, for a more generic approach with arbitrary depth:

```
def get_deep_attr(obj, *path):
    return reduce(getattr, path, obj)

def set_deep_attr(obj, value, *path)
    setattr(get_deep_attr(obj, path[:-1]), path[-1], value)

print get_deep_attr(rsyslog, 'instance{}'.format(this_instance_number), attribute)
set_deep_attr(rsyslog, variable, 'instance{}'.format(this_instance_number), attribute)
```

Comment: Martijn, how then do we populate deeper objects?  If I need to edit my original question I will.  In a nutshell I'm looping to create rsyslog.<instance#>, and within that loop looping to create the rsyslog.<instance#>.<attribute>s.  Your setattr appears to be setting the object's attribute back to whatever you just read, but I will be setting unique values.  Is it possible to use settattr like this?:  setattr(rsyslog, instance5.startupscript, "/etc/init.d/sample")?  By extension then how do we replace "instance5.startupscript" dynamically?

Comment: @JustinHaynes: updated with a generic approach to allow for arbitrary-depth attribute chains.

Comment: @JustinHaynes: the original approach will still work just fine though, you must've futzed some variable somewhere in your loop.