# recursive access to dictionary and modification

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'key1': {'key2': {'foo': 'bar'} } }
```

and I would like to append an entry to key1->key2->key3 with value 'blah' yielding:

```
my_dict = {'key1': {'key2': {'foo': 'bar', 'key3': 'blah'} } }
```

I am looking for a generic solution that is independent of the number of keys, i.e. key1->key2->key3->key4->key5 should work as well, even though keys from key3 on downwards do not exist. So that I get:

```
my_dict = {'key1': {'key2': {'foo': 'bar', 'key3': {'key4': {'key5': 'blah'} } } } }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating dictionary using list/tuple elements as key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024982/creating-dictionary-using-list-tuple-elements-as-key)

Comment: The techniques in my answer there apply here too; use `reduce()` to walk to the innermost dictionary (creating additional dictionaries as needed).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for the hint. But I think this is only the first half of my problem. Now, after creating the key, how do I access it given the list of keys and the value?

Comment: `target = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path[:-1], my_dict)` is the path to the right dictionary (since `path[-1]` is just the list key to the actual value), then `target[path[-1]] = 'blah'` does the last step.

Comment: Similar answer using `reduce()` to traverse objects and set attributes instead of dictionaries and keys: [How to use string formatting to dynamically assign variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22349385)

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, reduce is on this weekends to-read list ;) Thanks. If you put it into an answer, you'll get the check. I think it is a slightly different questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to traverse a series of nested dictionaries:

```
def get_nested(d, path):
    return reduce(dict.__getitem__, path, d)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def get_nested(d, path):
...     return reduce(dict.__getitem__, path, d)
... 
>>> my_dict = {'key1': {'key2': {'foo': 'bar', 'key3': {'key4': {'key5': 'blah'}}}}}
>>> get_nested(my_dict, ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5'))
'blah'
```

This version throws an exception when a key doesn't exist:

```
>>> get_nested(my_dict, ('key1', 'nonesuch'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_nested
KeyError: 'nonesuch'
```

but you could replace `dict.__getitem__` with `lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {})` to have it create empty dictionaries instead:

```
def get_nested_default(d, path):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path, d)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def get_nested_default(d, path):
...     return reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path, d)
... 
>>> get_nested_default(my_dict, ('key1', 'nonesuch'))
{}
>>> my_dict
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {'key4': {'key5': 'blah'}}, 'foo': 'bar'}, 'nonesuch': {}}}
```

To *set* a value at a given path, traverse over all keys but the last one, then use the final key in a regular dictionary assignment:

```
def set_nested(d, path, value):
    get_nested_default(d, path[:-1])[path[-1]] = value
```

This uses the `get_nested_default()` function to add empty dictionaries as needed:

```
>>> def set_nested(d, path, value):
...     get_nested_default(d, path[:-1])[path[-1]] = value
... 
>>> my_dict = {'key1': {'key2': {'foo': 'bar'}}}
>>> set_nested(my_dict, ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5'), 'blah')
>>> my_dict
{'key1': {'key2': {'key3': {'key4': {'key5': 'blah'}}, 'foo': 'bar'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Martijn Pieters's excellent answer would be to use a nested `defaultdict`, rather than a regular dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nested = lambda: defaultdict(nested) # nested dictionary factory

my_dict = nested()
```

You can set values by using regular nested dictionary access semantics, and empty dictionaries will be created to fill the middle levels as necessary:

```
my_dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = "blah"
```

This of course requires that the number of keys be known in advance when you write the code to set the value. If you want to be able to handle a variable-length list of keys, rather than a fixed number, you'll need functions to do the getting and setting for you, like in Martijn's answer.